# non sha256 characters

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to store more than one sha256 hashed strings as a single string with a separator.  I was using MD5 previously and was able to use a ",".  But it seems that the comma is one of the characters generated by a sha256 hash.  So my question is: Are there any *printable* (I realize some non printable can be used) ASCII characters that will never be used in a sha256 hash?

Comment: SHA256 hashes are always 32 bytes.  So you don't really need the separator at all if you count bytes or do some arithmetic to grab a specific hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't converting the generated sha256 hash to hex format before, since the hashes themselves are just a number (hence a comma can appear in an MD5 hash).

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  It looks to me like the bytes can be anywhere from 00 to ff, so I'll get some non-printable characters if I interpret as ASCII.  I'll just store the hex values as ASCII (unfortunate that it will double the size though).